# Defining variable type in Netbeans PHP

Tags: php, netbeans

I have found a way to say netbeans type of variable in such way:

```
/* @var $variablename Type */
```

However in this case there are no hints (Database is my class):

```
 //model.php
 abstract class Model {
      /* @var $db Database */
      protected $db;
      (...)
 }

 //Mymodel.php
 class MyModel extends Model {
      (...)
       $this->db-> //no hints
      (...)
 }
```

Is it Netbeans limit or rather my mistake?

Comment: Well, all class (Database, Model and MyModel) files are in the same folder, in Model class I've got database hints, however I've got them even without such comment, in MyModel I've got hints from parent class, but no hints with MyModel->db. Version 7.2

Comment: The type of variable needs to prefix the variable name, it should read `@var Database $db` rather than the other way around. Other possible problem sources: wrong include path (can you STRG+click into your $db variable?) or property access in class rather than in class method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, define the variable type first, like this:

```
/* @var Database $db This is my Database object */
```

And secondly I would suggest to use phpdoc commenting, like:

```
class Model {

/**
 * @var Database $db This is my Database object
 */
protected $db;
```

Should have no issues then...

Comment: +1 You made me realise what the problem was. I've added an answer for completeness.

Comment: Hadn't seen there was only one asterisk following the slash, well observed.

Answer (score 8):

NetBeans can make use of two similar yet different comment annotations:

1. Good old [phpdoc](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.var.pkg.html) block comments, that start with `/**` and are placed right before the item *definition*:

   ```
   /**
    * @var Database $db Database connection instance
    */
   protected $db;
   ```
2. [Variable type](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/defining-a-variable-type-in-comment-ii) inline comments, that start with `/*` and are placed somewhere before the item *use*:

   ```
   $foo = $this->db;
   /* @var $foo Database*/
   $foo->...
   ```

The second type comes in handy when docblock comments are either not available or not helpful, e.g. you are using a third-party library that isn't documented or your variable type cannot be tracked automatically.

You were basically using syntax for #2 in the context for #1 ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I was trying the (double-star) /** comment within a method.  Changed that to /* and voila.